# What is known about $\displaystyle \sum_k{a^{b^k}}$?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series, applications

What is known about $\displaystyle \sum_k{a^{b^k}}$?  *I am very interested in the possible applications of this series.*

I have asked about this on Mathematics Stack Exchange [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/637300/what-is-known-about-doubly-exponential-series).

I'm wondering if there has been any research on this particular type of series, or what similar ideas/topics are out there.

Please be gentle. I'm not an expert, but I'm wondering if someone could possibly point me in the right direction.

Comment: Not an application per se, but if you think of this series as a power series in $a$, then this kind of series appears in the study of lacunary functions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_series#An_elementary_result

Comment: If $b$ is an integer and $a$ is the reciprocal of an integer, then you get a beautiful continued fraction expansion (see the articles http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0022-314X(79)90040-4 and http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0022-314X(82)90047-6 by Jeffrey Shallit).

Answer (score 3):

The series $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^{b^k}$ is the most important example of a lacunary Taylor series, which have been studied quite a lot. One important theorem about them is the Hadamard gap theorem: $f$ does not extend analytically to any part of the boundary of the unit disc. [This paper](http://www.unalmed.edu.co/~jmramirezo/Jorge_Ramirez/English_files/On-the-path-properties-of-a-lacunary-power-series_PROC15.pdf) by Jensen, Pommerenke and Ramírez studies the properties of $f$ when $b=2$ (but many of the theorems probably generalize).

In the paper there are many theorems about how $f$ maps the radii $[0,\zeta]
,\zeta\in \partial \mathbb{D}$ of the unit disk. We for example have a ''central limit theorem'' from Salem and Zygmund: for any measurable $E\subset \partial \mathbb{D}$ we have
$$m(\{\zeta \in E:\Re(f(1-2^{-t}\zeta))\leq x\sqrt{\frac{t}{2}})\to \frac{m(E)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}dy$$
as $t\to \infty$, and the same holds for imaginary parts. Therefore, when we are ''close'' to the boundary of the disk, the bahavior of $f$ as a function of the direction $\zeta$ resembles normal distribution.

There is also an elegant law of iterated logarithms by Erdös, Gal and Weiss:
$$\limsup_{t\to \infty}\frac{f((1-2^{-t})\zeta)}{\sqrt{t\log \log t}}=1$$
for almost every $\zeta \in \partial \mathbb{D}$.

According to the paper, $f$ also has the property that the image of the unit disc is the whole complex plane.

Answer (score 1):

The famous Weierstrass continuous nowhere differentiable function
is $\Re\sum c^ne^{2\pi b^nx}.$
Setting $c=1$, we obtain your series with $a=e^{2\pi x}$.

Weierstrass function was studied in great detail by Hardy, TAMS 17 (1916) 301-325,
and by many other authors.

Comment: Isn't the Weierstrass function a sum of trigonometric exponentials  $e^{2\pi i b^n x}$ with $|c|<1$?

Comment: Yes. Except that $c$ is missing in your formula. I just noticed that if you put $c=1$ you obtain your function. You did not ask any specific question, so I do not discuss the real meaning of putting $c=1$.

Comment: I meant that the series $\sum_n c^n e^{2\pi i b^n}$ is the Weierstrass function. If you take $i$ away from the exponent, you get an analytic function instead of a nondifferentiable one.